# Jquery Remove Character from Input - working with a slight issue

Tags: jquery, forms, input, replace

I've written a small bit of jquery that checks an array as the user enters details into a form field.

I've set it so values in the array and what the user types are both checked as lowercase, this is working fine.

I've now added a line to allow me to stop the users entering invalid characters.

Again this works but has a slight issue in that it stops the use of the left & right arrows to move back and forth between characters in the input field.

and I don't know why !!

```
$(function(){
 $("input[name='name[]']").bind("change keyup", function() {
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$@#!£]/, ''));
    var names = ['rod','jane','freddy'];
    var names = $.map(names, function(n,i){return n.toLowerCase();});
    var results = ($.inArray(val, names) != -1) ? "GREY" : "WHITE";
    $(this).css("background-color", results);
  });
});
```

and I've created a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rhJ2n/)** that shows what happens.

If I remove the following line it works, but the invalid characters are then allowed.

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$@#!£]/, ''));
```

How can I get this to work but allow the arrow keys to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check on which key the user pressed and stop the function when he press it :

```
$("input[name='name[]']").bind("change keyup", function(e) { //Add the event as argument
    var keyAllowed = [37, 39]; //37 = left key code, 39 = right
    if($.inArray(e.which, keyAllowed) > -1) return; //Stop the function
    //Your code
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gagnonka/rhJ2n/1/

Comment: Thanks that works, BUT why would my line of script cause that issue ?

Comment: @MacMan because when you use `.val()` or `.value` in vanilla js, you replace the entire line, putting your cursor at the end.

Comment: if u paste `$@#!£` into th input field, it doesnt replace all, so add "g" (global match) to th regex: `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[$@#!£]/g, ''));`